How do I conduct a fake drive test protocol on macOS?
I came across a rather cheap harddrive brand Frafuo, and googled about it and came across the following post:
https://www.reddit.com/r/datarecovery/comments/t8u4yh/i_was_stupid_and_bought_a_cheap_external_harddrive/
In that post, I learnt that it is possible to "reprogram the [storage] device to report more capacity,and actually just overwrite the last 20% or so of the space repeatedly in order to suppress error messages."
I also learnt of systematic protocols that I can adopt from:
https://www.winusb.net/articles/fake-flash-test.html
and I wish to make it a point from now on to check or test every storage unit I purchase, before I use it to really write important files.
However, the article above is flash-drive specific, and looks like it uses Windows tools.
How may I conduct a similar protocol for HDDs on a macOS10.13 or macOS12 (the two Macs that I own run these versions)?
P.S.: I have seen a similar Apple SE post like:
Can I tell if a hard drive is usable or fake?
The answer in there mentions how to spot with the eye without testing if a harddrive is real or fake, which does not fully answer my concern. I'd like to really do a full test on a harddrive that can really make me close to 100% sure that a harddrive is usable, or authentic, even when I already know that I bought it from reliable sources.

Buy name-brand devices from reputable sources.

Please see my last sentence: "I'd like to really do a full test on a harddrive...even when I already know that I bought it from reliable sources.", which includes "name-brand devices from reputable sources"

What evidence will convince you it's authentic and usable?

@bmike, the answer by Linc Davis is a good enough answer. And do note I am intending to buy a fully reputable drive from a fully reputable store, and yet still wish to test it first.

Let's say the nominal capacity of the drive is 4 TiB. Write copies of a 4 GiB file to the drive until it's full. You should now have about 1000 copies. Test the CRC checksum of each one. If they all match the original, you're as sure as you can be that the drive is as advertised. That said, if you really care about the safety of your data, you won't trust it to a no-name drive, regardless of any test result.
Note that if the test drive is formatted as APFS, you have to make each copy from another device. Otherwise you'll be cloning rather than copying and the results won't mean anything. See:
Copy, move and clone files in APFS, a primer (eclecticlight.co). But APFS is unsuitable for hard drives because it lacks built-in defragmentation.

Command A, Command D repeated. One file becomes 2 becomes 4, 8, 16, ...

Linc Davis, @bmike, I can do this test to a HFS+ formatted drive with single partition, and then when I want to use it after confirming that the test result is authentic, reformat it again after that into as many HFS+ partitions as I want, to use it, right? The test result will still stand right? Or am I missing out on any intricacies involved in partitioning which I may not know about?

Partitioning won't invalidate the test result.
